# Displacement modifier un effected by UV Mapping

Tags: uv, displacement

So I was trying to make a tire in blender, and encountered a problem while trying to make the bumps and ridges on the rubber.

I have the following texture and UV Map:
[image]

When I plug this image texture into the displacement node and use that displacement in the material output, I do get a result similar to what I expected:
[image]

But since I was unable to increase the height (otherwise I would have used this option) I tried using the Displace modifier. But when using the same image for the texture used in this modifier, the model looks like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to increase the height of the displacement when using the node instead of the modifier? And why doesn't the displacement modifier displace the mesh according to the UV Map? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use this height map with a *Bump* node in order to fake the 3D relief. But if you want to use a *Displacement* node:

- First in the *Material* panel > *Settings*, enable *Displacement Only*:

[image]

- In the *Shader Editor*, put the *Displacement Midlevel* at 0 and the *Scale* at a low value, switch the *Image Editor* to *Non-Color* and select the *tire_bump* image:

[image]

- Also to have displacement you need to subdivide your mesh, you can apply a *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

Result:

[image]